# How to perform http request in frida js

Tags: javascript, android, frida

I use this project to hook android process.

https://github.com/iGio90/FridaAndroidInjector

it allows you to inject frida agents from an Android application.

it works perfect.

when I want to use it hook this function.

```
com.ex.MediaPlayMgr.play(final InputStream inputStream, final String str)
```

hook code is:

```
function log(what) {
    Java.performNow(function() {
        Java.use('android.util.Log').e("FridaAndroidInject", "kenshinx " + what.toString());
    });
}

Java.perform(function() {
        let MediaPlayMgr = Java.use("com.ex.MediaPlayMgr");
    MediaPlayMgr["play"].overload('java.io.InputStream', 'java.lang.String', 'boolean', 'boolean', 'int').implementation = function (inputStream, str, z, z2, i) {
//        this["play"](inputStream, str, z, z2, i);
//        Java.send({'str': str});
        log("step0:")
        var downloadTask = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          // 异步代码...
           log("step1:" + str)
           var OkHttpClient = Java.use("okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder").$new().build();
           log("step2:" + OkHttpClient)
           var request = Java.use("okhttp3.Request$Builder").$new().url("http://com.ex.com/api").build();
           log("step3:" + request)
           var response = OkHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
           log("step4:" + response)
           if (response) {
              resolve(response.byteStream(), "paimen")
           } else {
              reject(inputStream, str)
           }
        });
        log("step5:")
        function doPlay(stream, word) {
            log("stepx:" + stream + ", " + word)
            this.play(stream, word, z, z2, i);
        }
        log("step6:")
        downloadTask.then(doPlay, doPlay);
        log("step7:")
    };
});
```

log stopped in step3. no step4.
so how to do http request in js.

```
10:27:21.997 16391-16391 FridaAndroidInject   com...plication.floatball  E  kenshinx step0:
10:27:21.997 16391-16391 FridaAndroidInject   com...plication.floatball  E  kenshinx step1:哈哈哈
10:27:22.000 16391-16391 FridaAndroidInject   com...plication.floatball  E  kenshinx step2:okhttp3.OkHttpClient@1af90ef
10:27:22.003 16391-16391 FridaAndroidInject   com...plication.floatball  E  kenshinx step3:Request{method=GET, url=http://com.ex.com/api}
10:27:22.006 16391-16391 FridaAndroidInject   com...plication.floatball  E  kenshinx step5:
10:27:22.006 16391-16391 FridaAndroidInject   com...plication.floatball  E  kenshinx step6:
10:27:22.006 16391-16391 FridaAndroidInject   com...plication.floatball  E  kenshinx step7:
10:27:22.007 16391-16391 FridaAndroidInject   com...plication.floatball  E  kenshinx stepx:Error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, undefined
```

I try the java.net.URL, java.net.HTTPConnect, not work.
I want replace the inputStream in play() with my own stream.

Comment: Could be a threading problem (e.g. networking is not allowed on main thread). For the injected HTTP request I would use a custom server I control and then check on network level if the HTP request is executed at all.

Comment: so how to resolve the thread problem, i'm new in js, i tried Java.sechudle(). not work.

Comment: `// error here` Which error? Dont let us guess.

Comment: Try a GET with https protocol as test. The http protocol is blocked on Android 11+ devices by default.

Comment: I test on Android 9, and it didn't show error info. that's why i hava no clue to solving this problem at all @blackapps

Answer (score 2):

like robert said, it was a thread problem, fixed by following code.

```
            var OkHttpClient = Java.use("okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder").$new().build();
    log('step1:' + OkHttpClient)
    var request = Java.use("okhttp3.Request$Builder").$new().url("http://com.ex.api").tag(this).build();
    log('step2:' + request)
    var Callback = Java.use("okhttp3.Callback");
    log('step3:' + Callback)
    const DownloadCallback = Java.registerClass({
               name:'com.ka.tts.player.DownloadCallback',
               implements: [Callback],
               methods: {
                    onFailure(call, e) {
                        log('stepA:'+call)
                        var that = call.request().tag()
                        log('stepB:'+that)
                        var that1 = Java.cast(that, Java.use("com.ka.tts.player.audiotrack.AudioTrackPlayerImpl"))
                        Java.scheduleOnMainThread(function(){
                            that1.play(mediaResource.stream, str, i);
                        });
                    },
                    onResponse(call, response){
                       log('step4:' + call)
                       var that = call.request().tag()
                       log('step5:'+that)
                       var that1 = Java.cast(that, Java.use("com.ka.tts.player.audiotrack.AudioTrackPlayerImpl"))
                       try {
                          if (response.code() === 200) {
                             var stream = response.body().byteStream()
                             log("step6:" + stream)
                             Java.scheduleOnMainThread(function(){
                                that1.play(stream, str, i);
                             })
                          } else {
                             log("step7:")
                             Java.scheduleOnMainThread(function(){
                                that1.play(mediaResource.stream, str, i);
                             })
                          }
                          log("step8:")
                       } catch (e) {
                          log("error:" + e)
                          Java.scheduleOnMainThread(function(){
                            that1.play(mediaResource.stream, str, i);
                          })
                       }
                  },
               }
          });
    OkHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(DownloadCallback.$new());
```